# Folder for data_files in setup.py build (setuptools)

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to add `data_file` to `setup.py` project . I can use file from `/tmp/` directory, and cannot use it from current directory of the script:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

packages = find_packages("src")
foo_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/foo.dat'
print foo_path   # file exists and there full absolute path is printed:
                 # '/home/loom/myapp/foo.dat'

setup(name='myapp',
        version='0.2.0',
        url='http://loom.st',
        author='Loom',
        author_email='admin@loom.st',
        package_dir={'': 'src'},
        packages=packages,
        py_modules=['my_start'],
# 1.        data_files=[('lib/python', [foo_path])],
# 2.        data_files=[('lib/python', [/tmp/foo.dat])],
        setup_cfg=True,
        )
```

When the line `1.` is uncommented, then `python setup.py bdist_rpm` failed with message:

```
running install_data
error: can't copy '/home/loom/myapp/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD/myapp-0.2.0/foo.dat': doesn't exist or not a regular file
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.02mmV8 (%install)
```

When the line `2.` is uncommented, then build is completed ok and includes `foo.dat` (file `/tmp/foo.dat` exists)

Why the line `1.` induces error and how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you working under Windows or *nix? Try to remove the trailing `/` in `/home/loom/myapp/foo.dat/` while in `/tmp/foo.dat` it seems to be a file and not a dir

Comment: @linusg - I am working on *nix and `tmp` is in the root directory and file `/tmp/foo.dat` exists. I'll expand question, thank you

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. Try what I added to my comment please.

Comment: Maybe defining `foo_path` as `"./foo.dat"` if it's in the same directory as the setup file??

Comment: @linusg - `error: can't copy './foo.dat': doesn't exist or not a regular file` I started with it.

Comment: Try printing out your current working directory using `import os; print(os.getcwd())`. Maybe it's not set as the dir where `setup.py` and `foo.dat` are in...

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returned `/home/loom/myapp/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110162/discussion-between-loom-and-linusg).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that you've given the wrong path to `foo.dat`, it's given as a directory:

> /home/loom/myapp/foo.dat/

Just remove the trailing `/` at the end, so it's a path to a file:

> /home/loom/myapp/foo.dat

If the file really exists, all should be fine now.

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo in my question I fixed. Unfortunately the problem with folder still here.

Comment: Oops, will have a look on it one more time!